# How to change image height and width to CGPoint in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, image-processing, image-resizing

I am new in iOS.
I need help to image height,width to eight point to change like as crop image,in bottom i show image change height, width can you have any demo for this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should see this link hep you for your[see this](https://github.com/baris/ResizeImages) image height,width to eight point